# Can access previous contexts in simulator, but not on device running alpha with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

In the dialogflow console I have a context "order-followup" thats passed between follow up intents. I access a parameter from it using `agent.context.get('order-followup').parameters['chocolate-type']` using `dialogflow-fulfillment` 0.6.1, this works perfectly when testing with the simulator. But when I try using my action pushed to my alpha to test with a real physical assistant device, the context returns as `undefined`.

I've tested it on the follow up intent immediately following the intent its started in (and set to 10 lifespan) and it can't return it to me. Looking at the body of the json passed to firebase from my real device alpha test I can see the `order-followup` context in the data, but I can't `.get()` it.

It seems the simulator and real devices have differences?

Comment: have you tried it in the simulator with the alpha environment? what you're seeing seems quite unexpected - although there are differences between the simulator and devices, that shouldn't be one of them.

Comment: if I `console.log(agent.context.get('order-followup'))` in the draft version in simulator i get `{ name: 'order-followup', lifespan: 10, parameters: { 'chocolate-type.original': 'Vegan', 'chocolate-type': 'vegan' } }` but if I switch the simulator to alpha version I get `undefined`. Both are calling the same firebase function and I can't think of any significant changes on the console

Comment: (checked though toggling between draft and my alpha version) the only difference in the body json sent to my function I can see is the alpha's outputContexts names include `[...]agent/environments/__aog-16/users/-/sessions/[...]` where as the draft version is `[...]agent/sessions/[...]`. I made sure to publish a new alpa, so the draft and alpa are technically exactly the same as each other.

Comment: Can you please update the question with additional information instead of trying to provide it in comments? It is really difficult to follow in comments.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue in the dialogflow library: [https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/187](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/187)